# Multiple confirmation errors come up for destroy action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, assets

I have a running RoR (rails 4) project. I am having an issue with popup issues.

I believe that it has to do with my assets, but I'm not sure. I've looked around and some people have said it might be the order of requirements in the application.js file. Other searchs have said it may be with conflicting gems/requirements.

I have the gem mailboxer, and whenever I delete a message, it asks me multiple times. The amount of times it asks me can vary from 2-50 times. After I have clicked 'ok' several times it will eventually finish asking and run the action.

If I remove the:

```
data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }
```

It wont ask for the confirmation of course.

I have been having some other issues that I think are all related as well. My bootstrap dropdown menu only drops down once every 10 clicks maybe. Sometimes I have to refresh my site a few times before the dropdown actually drops.

Here is my gemfile:

```
ruby '2.1.5'
gem 'rails', '4.2.0'

gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate'
gem 'will_paginate' 
gem 'devise'
gem "mailboxer"

gem "simple_calendar"

gem 'chosen-rails'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.5'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'

gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# This gem is required for mailboxer, but included w/ fullcalendar
# gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do
      gem 'byebug'
      gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
        gem 'sqlite3'
      gem 'spring'
        gem 'railroady'
end

group :production do
     gem 'pg'
     gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

Application.js

```
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require chosen-jquery
//= require turbolinks
//= require messages
//= require_tree .
```

application.html.erb

```
<head>
    <div class="brand">Balern Education</div>
    <div class="address-bar">
        116-118 Lv Di Business Street | Bin Hai New Area, Tianjin | 1.860.226.8341
    </div>

  <title>Balern Edu.</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

<html lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="business-casual.css.scss" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="http://fonts.useso.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.useso.com/css?family=Josefin+Slab:100,300,400,600,700,100italic,300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
```

Comment: I think you need to add your actual code, as well as the line you're removing.

Comment: Is it your actual application.html.erb? Why is there `<html lang="en">` inside `<head>`?

Comment: this is a twitter-bootstrap theme. should that not be there? I am new to rails and am honestly not sure....

Comment: Please read http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_intro.asp Your HTML doesn't look valid at all.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you use Turbolinks.

Turbolinks doesn't reload the whole page, it only reloads the body (and some other things). Therefore if your javascript is in the body it's loaded multiple times and then it asks you for multiple confirmations.

You can solve this by moving this line from the body into the head:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

Comment: Thanks,
I'm not quite sure what you mean though. I only have turbolinks in one view which is my application.html.erb (edited, and posted above). The 'javascript_include_tag' is not anywheres else in my application.

Comment: I updated my answer. Please try to move `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>` into the `head` of your html

Comment: Im still a bit confused by what you mean. Above, I have included my application.html.erb file. This is the only file I have that contains:
 `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>`. In my code example above, it IS in the head and not the body. Do you mean to remove the repetition of turbolinks from my `stylesheet_link_tag`?

Comment: Ok, can you try to disable Turbolinks to see if it has something to do with it or not at all?

Comment: I removed `'data-turbolinks-track' => true` from both of these lines  `<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>`. I still generated the confirmation error with 2 popups. Here: http://cl.ly/image/3821101B0C3v, http://cl.ly/image/1E0W333c3401 .

The problem seems pretty random. Sometimes it seems like it works when I delete one message. But then I go to delete another, and it will ask me 2 or 3 times.

Comment: And is it still there if you remove Turbolinks from your Gemfile?

Comment: I removed the turbolinks gem and made my application.html.erb look like this:   `<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application'%>
  <%= javascript_include_tag%>`. This however breaks pieces of my sites functionality. It did however 'fix' the multiple confirmation issue. It doesn't ask me for ANY confirmation like this.

Comment: Your JS is not included. It has to be `<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %> <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>`

Comment: I cannot do this though, can I. When I copy & paste the code you gave me, to replace those two lines I get an error. http://cl.ly/image/2x3f1q283q1a. Leaving the `'application'` part makes it want to use turbolinks.

Comment: Ohh, I messed that last step you gave me up. I had to remove turbolinks from my application.js file. With that being said, I am still getting the error though.

Comment: Very weird, it should work http://blog.steveklabnik.com/posts/2013-06-25-removing-turbolinks-from-rails-4

Comment: I followed that blog and have succesfully removed turbolinks. I however am still getting 2/3 confirmations everytime I delete a message from mailboxer.

Comment: Sorry then I have no idea what's wrong. Maybe check your HTML layout.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I fixed it...
I am not getting the confirmation error anymore. I didn't move any lines but I changed my *application.html.erb* file. I changed the line:  `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>` to `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-eval' => false %>`.

GitHub: [data-confirm firing more than once #244](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/issues/244)